# VTK does not render polygon correctly

Tags: rendering, polygon, vtk

I have a VTK 6.3 program that I have distilled down to the listing below.

When I run it, the rendered polygon is not correct. It should be a quadrilateral with another attached quadrilateral on the side, not this wacky thing:

[image: Bad polygon rendering]

It looks as though the polygon triangulation is in error, and a rogue triangle winks on and off when you spin the polygon around.

I believe that my polygon has been specified correctly: counter-clockwise and non-self-intersecting.

I have dug through the VTK code hoping to find a way to change the triangulation method. The VTKPolygon class contains several different triangulation methods, but it is not clear if one can manually set the method.

If someone has a suggestion for troubleshooting this, I would be very grateful.

As I have said, I believe the listing is close to the minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem.

Also, as it's been noted in the comments, this behavior is fixed in VTK version 8.0. However, I am running RHEL 7.4, and installing version 7 or 8 of VTK has not been straight-forward. VTK seems to want a newer version of OpenGL than what is available for RHEL 7.4.

```
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkCellArray.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkPolygon.h>
#include <vtkProperty.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct P { float x, y, z; };
    vector<P> p;
    p.push_back (P {8.0, 3.0, 0.0});
    p.push_back (P {7.0, 5.0, 0.0});
    p.push_back (P {1.0, 3.0, 0.0});
    p.push_back (P {1.0, 2.0, 0.0});
    p.push_back (P {0.0, 3.0, 0.0});
    p.push_back (P {0.0, 1.0, 0.0});
    p.push_back (P {1.0, 1.0, 0.0});
    p.push_back (P {1.0, 0.0, 0.0});

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolygon> poly = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolygon>::New();
    poly->GetPointIds()->SetNumberOfIds(p.size ());

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> polygons = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < p.size (); ++i)
    {
        points->InsertNextPoint (p[i].x, p[i].y, p[i].z);
        poly->GetPointIds()->SetId(i, i);
    }

    polygons->InsertNextCell(poly);
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polydata = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();

    polydata->SetPoints(points);
    polydata->SetPolys(polygons);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputData(polydata);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> buildingActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    buildingActor->SetMapper(mapper);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    renderer->AddActor(buildingActor);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
    renderWindow->Render();
    renderWindowInteractor->Start ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I ran your code as it is with VTK 8.0, I get two quadrilaterals joined at a common edge.

Comment: @AmitSingh Thanks! I guess it's time to upgrade.

Comment: Actually, I tried to upgrade, but my distribution, RHEL 7.4, does not have the version of OpenGL that is needed by newer versions of VTK. This has been noted in the post.

Comment: Are you using a virtual machine ?

Comment: @MathieuWestphal No, I'm not using a virtual machine

Comment: RHEL should support the version of OpenGL you need. Can you precise the error you get when building/using VTK 8 on RHEL 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think VTK has some trick with coordinates origin. I adopted your source to VTK 8.1.1. I changed coordinates set to get two triangles with different orientation in space

[image]

I placed modified source below

```
#include "vtkAutoInit.h"
#define vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT 2(vtkRenderingOpenGL2, vtkInteractionStyle)
#include "stdafx.h"


#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkCellArray.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkPolygon.h>
#include <vtkProperty.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct P { float x, y, z; };
    vector<P> p;

    p.push_back(P{ 8.0, 8.0, 3.0 });
    p.push_back(P{ 8.0, 1.0, 0.0 });
    p.push_back(P{ 1.0, 8.0, 0.0 });
    p.push_back(P{ 1.0, 1.0, 3.0 });
    p.push_back(P{ 8.0, 1.0, 0.0 });


    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolygon> poly = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolygon>::New();
    poly->GetPointIds()->SetNumberOfIds(p.size());

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> polygons =vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < p.size(); ++i)
    {
        points->InsertNextPoint(p[i].x, p[i].y, p[i].z);
        poly->GetPointIds()->SetId(i, i);
    }

    polygons->InsertNextCell(poly);
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polydata = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();

    polydata->SetPoints(points);
    polydata->SetPolys(polygons);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputData(polydata);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> buildingActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    buildingActor->SetMapper(mapper);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    renderer->AddActor(buildingActor);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();

    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();

    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
    renderWindow->Render();
    renderWindowInteractor->Start();

    return 0;
}
```